# Question(s) about asking Questions

Tags: discussion

I just need some clarification about links when we ask questions. Here is how I understand it at the moment.

1) We need to use 3rd party image websites such as Imgur.com to host pictures we need to use in our post.

2) However we can’t link to other websites such as Goodyear tires if I had a question how to do tread of a tire.

3) What if we need an image from a third party website to help explain a problem we’re having?

I hope that I have anything correct.

Thank you,

Answer (score 4):

To clarify about the images. Yes they are hosted externally, **however** it is not the same as a 3rd part image site, like imgur. SE has an special agreement with imgur. All the images uploaded through the image tools in the editor (see Duarte's answer) are through this domain: https://i.stack.imgur.com/. All "normal" imgur uploads simply go through https://i.imgur.com/. Aside from the license differences, images through the SE channel will stick around forever*, there is no such guarantee for imgur images.

There should be **zero externally hosted images**. (That goes for images where you do not own the copyright, reupload it through SE, and give attribution with a link back to the original.) Here is one of [my questions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/69989/2217) as an example.

For your Goodyear tires example, do something like this:

> [image]
>   <sub>Image from [Goodyear](https://www.goodyear.com/en-US/tires/assurance-all-season)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Use the builtin tools to upload your image like you would a local one.

Just press the *Image* button from the toolbar, use the *Paste link* option and paste the URL of the desired image.

[image]

If that fails you may also download it locally, then upload using the *Browse* button.

Make sure you are not infringing any copyright. As a matter of courtesy you should probably mention the source of the image and paste a link to the original as a footer note

Comment: ...which might not be the best idea, when it comes to copyrighted material. It seems, StackExchange goes completely "nastyass honeybadger don't care" about that, but that might change in the future. Article 13 and so on...